# Переменная вне зоны видимости (вроде)

Tags: python

При вызове возвращает `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'path' referenced before assignment`
Как это решить и из за чего питону так сложно найти переменную?

Пробовал определять переменную вне условия и блока try-except, но это не помогло.

P.s. Данный код это функция которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку.

```
try:
    if ...:
        path = f'...'
    elif ...:
        path = f'...'

    with open(path,'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as f_1:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не выполняются ни иф, ни елиф, то переменная не определена. Это и происходит.

Comment: все гениальное —  просто